# Integers - error: ".class" expected , ";" expected and not a statement

Tags: java, minecraft-forge

So I have a problem with the integers. At first, I am trying to find a solution since days and still don't know what to do. As you can see, I want to give int points: 10 and rest 0 (needed for later on to give away skill points). In Skills.* I gave the skill names and points private int, this.* , getter and setter. In Profile.* same as in Skills but only for Skills but no int.

Three problems: 1. int points gets error .class expected , 2. every : should be put as ; and 3. 10 is not a statement.

```
package PowerSystem.managers;

import java.util.UUID;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;

import PowerSystem.components.Skills;
import PowerSystem.components.Profile;

import PowerSystem.Main;

public class ProfileManager {

    private Main main;
    private Map<UUID, Profile> profiles = new HashMap<>();
    
    public ProfileManager(Main main) {
        this.main = main;
    }

    public Profile createNewProfile(Player player) {
        Skills skills = new Skills(int points: 10, int health: 0, int strength: 0, int defense: 0, int speed: 0, int intelligence: 0);
        Profile profile = new Profile(skills);
        profiles.put(player.getUniqueId(), profile);
        return profile;
        
    }

    public Profile getPlayerProfile(UUID uuid) {
        return profiles.get(uuid);
    }

}
```

Comment: `Skills(int points: 10, int health: 0, int strength: 0, int defense: 0, int speed: 0, int intelligence: 0);` You should just use the values, not type and variable name information. `Skills(10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);`

Comment: Please read: [Can I ask only one question per post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post)

Comment: It looks like you've confused Objective-C and Java syntax in your constructor call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is wrong:

```java
Skills skills = new Skills(int points: 10, int health: 0, int strength: 0, int defense: 0, int speed: 0, int intelligence: 0);
```

You only give values to the constructor/method/function and not names and types. So the correct way to do this is:

```java
Skills skills = new Skills(10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Still, you would have to check the order that you have in your constructor, so that the values are appointed to the attributes they are meant to.